I2C Sensor Returning 0's on Pico but works Perfectly on RPi 3
I'm at my wits end over an ENS160 sensor I have working perfectly with a Raspberry Pi 3 (running full Linux OS and Python), but refuses to return any data when interfacing through a Raspberry Pi Pico with MicroPython.
Long story short, I purchased ENS160 + AHT21 breakout boards (two sensors, one board). All of them worked quite well with the Raspberry Pi Pico through MicroPython... for a period of time. After a number of days of continuous reading, the ENS160 readings would eventually start returning 0's for all three readings (AQI, TVOC, and ECO2). Initially, it was intermittent and I was able to do some configuration to get it back to life again. But as time went on, they grew more and more unreliable with the 0's coming back more frequently. At this point, many of the sensors simply don't return any data at all, no matter how I configure them. There is also no sign of any error being logged by the ENS160 from what I can tell. The AHT21 sensors all continue to work perfectly, so I don't think it is a problem involving the I2C lines.
What makes this absolutely puzzling: as soon as I wire one of these sensors (that were proven to not work on the Pico) to a Raspberry Pi 3 (running full Linux OS), it works perfectly. Data comes in, fully reliable, never misses a beat. I've tracked the exact register reads and writes by the Raspberry Pi 3 to the sensor and mimicked them completely with the Pico in MicroPython, both at initialization and read; no luck.
What I've tried:

Maybe the Pico's 5V (or 3.3V which I tried too) power supply is unstable. I tried external power. Same results.
Adding I2C pull-up resistors when interfacing with the Pi Pico, ranging from 10k ohms to 220 ohms. Same results.
Using a range of clock speeds (frequencies) - everything from 50,000 Hz to 400,000 Hz. Same results.

I've spent weeks now trying to figure out the issue. I've documented a lot of my trials in this GitHub repo here.
How could this be? I was going to chalk this up as a faulty sensor from a poor manufacturer, but this can't be the case as it works perfectly as soon as I hook it up with the Raspberry Pi 3. Any thoughts are appreciated, thank you!

Is 'MicroPython' a supported language in RPi Pico... by that I mean is it supported by Raspberry Pi - or is it only supported by Adafruit?  FWIW: I use the Pico C interface, I do a fair amount of I2C, and I've not had an issue (like the one you've described)! But the other thing I've noticed is that Raspberry Inc does not put their "A-Team" on Pico!!

You have to use a micropython library.

Your unlisted code doesn't work but we aren't mind readers
